# Declarative Service bind-Method not found

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi

I want to use a declarative service, but an error is thrown that the bind method ist not accesible or not found:

!MESSAGE [SCR] ComponentReference.bind(): bind method 'setAreaManagment' is not found or it is not accessible!

I can't find my mistake. Here is my service interface:

IManagmentService

```
public interface IAreaManagmentService {
    SurfacePolygon getAreaByDatabaseID(int id);

    void setAreaVisibility(int databaseId, boolean visible);

    public void addArea(Integer objectId, Integer databaseId, double biggestLat, double biggestLon, double smallestLat,
            double smallestLon, String name, Date date);

    void removeAllAreas();

    public LinkedList<DisplayedArea> getAreas();
}
```

A class called GlobeView (extends ViewPart) implements this interface.

Here is the XML-File where the service is 'published'

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<scr:component xmlns:scr="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/scr/v1.1.0" name="visualization-servcieprovider">
   <implementation class="GlobeView"/>
   <service>
      <provide interface="IAreaManagmentService"/>
   </service>
</scr:component>
```

And this is the XML-File where the service should be bound:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<scr:component xmlns:scr="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/scr/v1.1.0" enabled="true" name="visualization-detailsview">
   <implementation class="DetailsView"/>
   <reference bind="setAreaManagment" cardinality="1..1" interface="IAreaManagmentService" name="IAreaManagmentService" policy="dynamic" unbind="unsetAreaManagment"/>
</scr:component>
```

These two methods are in the DetailsView.java

```
  public void setAreaManagment(IAreaManagmentService areaManagment) {
        System.out.println("AreaManagmentSet");

        this.areaManagment = areaManagment;

        System.out.println("WAS SET " + this.areaManagment);
    }

    public void unsetAreaManagment(IAreaManagmentService areaManagmentIn) {
        System.out.println("AreaManagmentUnSet");
        this.areaManagment = null;
    }
```

(and there is a private IAreaManagmentService areaMangment of course ;-) )

Where is my mistake? I read the fab tutorial from Lars Vogella, but I can't find my mistake

Edit: I added Service-Component: OSGI-INF/serviceprovider.xml, OSGI-INF/managmentConsumer.xml to my Manifest as well

Comment: You don't specify any package-names in your service-descriptors - are you sure there is no ambiguity?

Comment: Yes. You need fully qualified type names. You also need to make sure the service provider and service consumer are using the same package containing the service type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things that might be the issue:

1) Make sure your OSGI-INF folder is on the build path by selecting it in the build tab of the manifest editor.

2) Add these attributes to both of your services activate="activate" immediate="true" that forces the bundle to activate.

3) Another tip would be to remove the policy from dynamic to "static" and I bet that will solve your problem. - Duncan

P.S
The other thing I don't see is a fully qualified class name your implementation classes.

Answer (score 1):

This has been some years ago; however I got the same error message today. I had a different issue:

I forgot to make the service provider class implement the service interface. Probably the OSGi server was unable to cast the instance to the interface, and was therefore unable to use my method whose parameter was the interface. To fix the issue, I just had to add a `implements MyInterface`.